# localhost: ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME while running start-dfs.sh

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I am beginner trying to set up Hadoop and a single node cluster and getting the error below when trying to run start-dfs.sh.

```
duser@aisling-VirtualBox:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME
Starting datanodes
localhost: ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME
Starting secondary namenodes [aisling-VirtualBox]
aisling-VirtualBox: ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME
2021-10-18 11:51:11,568 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

The configurations in my .bashrc file look like:

```
    #HADOOP VARIABLES START
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
    export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

Im not sure what the error could be, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Edit this in your mapred-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name> 
      <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
      </value>
     </property>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).